# \makecell in the header: how to get rid of the space after the last column of the table?

Tags: tables, siunitx, makecell

This table is perfect for me except for the space left at the end:

[image]

How can I eliminate it? `@{}` doesn't work!

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{S[table-format=3]}@{}}
    \toprule 
     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Lions} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ducks} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell{Ducks and\\ Lions}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Tizio & 1 & 10 & 100\tabularnewline
    Caio & 20 & 200 & 2\tabularnewline
    Sempronio & 300 & 3 & 30\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need  the `\multicolumn` spec to include `@{}`:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{3}{S[table-format=3]}@{}}
    \toprule 
     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Lions} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ducks} & \multicolumn{1}{l@{}}{\makecell{Ducks and\\ Lions}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Tizio & 1 & 10 & 100\tabularnewline
    Caio & 20 & 200 & 2\tabularnewline
    Sempronio & 300 & 3 & 30\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```